# Improve query: Select data from mysql table beyond certain point without primary key

Tags: mysql, select

I have written following query which runs in about 40 secs on my local server but keeps on running forever on the hosted mysql server.
Can somebody please help and identify how it can be improved?

```
Set @rownum = 0;
Set @rownum1 = 0;
explain select * from 
(select *, @rownum1:=@rownum1+1 as ida from xvp_tenant_683.activity_archive_90) tbl1
where tbl1.ida >
(select id from
(select *, @rownum:=@rownum+1 as id from xvp_tenant_683.activity_archive_90) tbl
where ctype = 'WRAPUP' and dtStart = '2015-10-01 17:08:59' and uid='30774' and 
cprofiletype = 'inbound' and pid = '53');
```

Table structure is:

```
CREATE TABLE `activity_archive_90` (
  `cType` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `dtStart` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '1900-01-01 00:00:00',
  `dtEnd` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '1900-01-01 00:00:00',
  `iDuration` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `dRevenue` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `uId` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `cUserName` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `cProfileType` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `pId` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ccId` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ibProfiles` text,
  `obProfiles` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cType`,`dtStart`,`uId`,`cProfileType`,`pId`),
  KEY `cType` (`cType`),
  KEY `dtStart` (`dtStart`),
  KEY `dtEnd` (`dtEnd`),
  KEY `uId` (`uId`),
  KEY `pId` (`pId`),
  KEY `ccId` (`ccId`),
  KEY `cProfileType` (`cProfileType`),
  KEY `cUserName` (`cUserName`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Explain statement result on hosted server are:

```
# id, select_type, table, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, Extra
1, PRIMARY, <derived2>, ALL, , , , , 333708, Using where
3, UNCACHEABLE SUBQUERY, <derived4>, ALL, , , , , 333708, Using where
4, DERIVED, activity_archive_90, ALL, , , , , 333708, 
2, DERIVED, activity_archive_90, ALL, , , , , 333708,
```

Explain statement result on my local server are:

```
# id, select_type, table, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, Extra
1, PRIMARY, <derived2>, ALL, , , , , 333525, Using where
3, UNCACHEABLE SUBQUERY, <derived4>, ref, <auto_key0>, <auto_key0>, 47, const,const,const,const,const, 10, Using index condition
4, DERIVED, zzz_activity_archive_90, ALL, , , , , 333525, 
2, DERIVED, zzz_activity_archive_90, ALL, , , , , 333525,
```

I notice the second result uses a key which could be the reason for faster result on my local server? How can I include this key on hosted server (I do not have access to alter table on hosted server)

Comment: Adding an explanation what your query does would make it easier to grasp for readers.

Comment: I am simply trying to get data post a certain row from a table in mysql. This is because I have to sync my local / cloud database from a client database on a regular basis. So I have written this query to get the new data which comes on a daily basis.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why not use a numeric index on that table vs using a value that you increment? Also, your explain statements shows that the query that you're running has to look at 333708 records, is that the entire record set in the database? If so, that means it's doing a full table scan which means you have to optimize your query and rethink your indexes.

Comment: How on earth do you manage to insert anything into that table with so many indexes?

Comment: @ Hatem Jaber, I can't alter the table on hosted server. It is what is available to me, nor I can add/remove indexes. Can you please suggest a better way in which I can use numeric index (without altering source table) so that I don't have to use a value to increment?

Comment: @e4c5 Its not my table, bound to work with it :(

Comment: You should threaten to quit! this is a horrible design and if this is any indication the other tables are probably worse! Take for example the index on cType , it's completely redundant because ctype is also the first column in the multi column primary key. So cType will probably never be used in any query.

Comment: @e4c5, good idea but i can't. would like to take it as a challenge and sort it out.